# Behaviour of kafka stream application when offset commit isn't being done either by application (and auto commit off)

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I want to know what behaviour of kafka streams would be when (using low level API) `auto commit` is turned off and **application don't do explicit commit?**

In case application is restarted (auto commit off, and application itself don't do explicit commit of offsets) will application read from beginning always? What will be behaviour of the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kafka Streams does commit offsets based on `commit.interval.ms` configs (default is 30 seconds). Thus, even if you request a commit, commits happen regularly. In general, it's sufficient to rely on Kafka Streams' implicit commits (requesting commits explicitly is not necessary for most applications).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am asking what behaviour of application would be when we set parameter `enable.auto.commit` is set to false and application isn't doing any commits. will committed offset be undefined?

Comment: `enable.auto.commit` is a consumer config and has no impact on Kafka Streams that will always commit based on `commit.interval.ms`. (In fact, to give Kafka Streams full control when commits happen, `enable.auto.commit` is always set to `false` for the internal consumers Kafka Streams uses and you cannot even enable it.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So this flag `enable.auto.commit` isn't applicable for kafka streams. Could you please point me to source code where it's overriding this flag for internal client?

Comment: Correct (as documented in the JavaDocs https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/StreamsConfig.java#L118). The overwrite happens here: https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/StreamsConfig.java#L1003

Comment: I have posted a new question,  if you can answer would be of great help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61622414/kafka-stateful-stream-processor-with-statestore-behind-the-scenes

Answer (score 2):

Kafka Streams automatically sets auto commits to disabled.

What is your `auto.offset.reset`? If latest, then it'll always start at the latest offset if there is no group for the `application.id`. Streams isn't special; this is the same logic as *any* consumer group.

If there is a group, then you start a terminal process (foreach, print, to, etc), then the offset will be committed. And you can enable transactional processing to get exactly once semantics.

---

Most of this is covered in the docs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I didn't get this part: "Kafka Streams automatically sets auto commits to disabled." -> Does every kafka streams turn it off irrespective of what has been specified --> "enable.auto.commit".

Comment: Yes. [Docs say so, at least](https://kafka.apache.org/25/documentation/streams/developer-guide/config-streams#enable-auto-commit)