# Kafka Stateful Stream processor with statestore: Behind the scenes

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am trying to understand `Stateful` `Stream processor`.

As I understand in this type of stream-processor, it maintains some sort of state using `State Store`.

I came to know, one of the ways to implement `State Store` is using `RocksDB`. Assuming the following `topology` (and only one processor being `stateful`)

A->B->C ; processor B as stateful with **local** state store and `changelog` **enabled**.  I am using low level API.

Assuming the sp listens on a single kafka topic, say `topic-1` with 10 partitions.

I observed, that when the application is started (2 instances in different physical machines and `num.stream.threads` = 5), then for `state store` it creates directory structure which 
has something like below:

0_0 , 0_1, 0_2.... 0_9 (Each machines has five so total 10 partitions).

I was going through some online material where it said we should create a `StoreBuilder` and attach it topology using `addStateStore()` ***instead*** of  **creating a state store within a processor.**

Like:

```
topology.addStateStore(storeBuilder,"processorName")

Ref also: org.apache.kafka.streams.state.Store
```

I didn't understand what is the difference **in attaching a storeBuilder to topology vs actually creating a statestore within processor**. What is the differences between them?

The second part: For statestore it creates directory like: 0_0, 0_1 etc. Who and how it gets created? Is there some sort of  1:1 mapping between the kafka topics (at which sp is listening) ande the number of directories that gets created for `State Store`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I didn't understand what is the difference in attaching a storeBuilder to topology vs actually creating a statestore within processor. What is the differences between them?

In order to let Kafka Streams manage the store for you (fault-tolerance, migration), Kafka Streams needs to be aware of the store. Thus, you give Kafka Streams a `StoreBuilder` and Kafka Streams creates and manages the store for you.

If you just create a store inside your processor, Kafka Streams is not aware of the store and the store won't be fault-tolerant.

> For statestore it creates directory like: 0_0, 0_1 etc. Who and how it gets created? Is there some sort of 1:1 mapping between the kafka topics (at which sp is listening) ande the number of directories that gets created for State Store?

Yes, there is a mapping. The store is shared base in the number of input topic partitions. You also get a "task" per partition and the task directories are name `y_z` with `y` being the sub-topology number and `z` being the partition number. For your simple topology you only have one sub-topology to all directories you see have the same `0_` prefix.

Hence, you logical store has 10 physical shards. This sharding allows Kafka Streams to mirgrate state when the corresponding input topic partition is assigned to a different instance. Overall, you can run up to 10 instanced and each would process one partition, and host one shard of your store.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. How can we "just attach" the state store (that is not being controlled by Kafka Stream). Is it like doing `new StateStore...` directly on the processor ?For the case when it is being controlled by Kafka Streams (passing `StoreBuilder`), could you please help point the source at which it creates these directory structure (0_0, 0_1...). I tried to find myself by creating a sample SP and debugged it, but didn't hit the exact point where it creates this kind of structure. Thanks for your expert answers and time.

Comment: I never tries to just call `new StateStore` inside a processor... So I am not sure if this would actually work. The API is designed to provide the `StoreBuilder` and if you use the classed differently, you are "on your own" as you enter uncharted territory.---The overall process of task creation and state management is rather complex and distributed over many classes, so it's hard to point you to some code.

Comment: After a task is created (https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/internals/TaskManager.java#L302-L312) it will be initialed. During the initializing stores are registered and the task directories are created (https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/internals/StateDirectory.java#L108). Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers, they help a lot to understand, hard to find info on net.

Comment: Well. Your inquire is about internals... Always hard to get information about it....

Comment: BTW, I have gone thru #Ask Confluent, and it is really awesome